# How to trigger Whatsapp Desktop by html link in Windows Google Chrome

Tags: whatsapp

According to [official Whatsapp documenttion](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030), if you want to make a clickable html link that triggers a new chat window in Whatsapp, regardless of (1) the destination phone number being in your contacts or not and (2) of OS (works in Web, iOS and Android), all you have to do is create a link like this:

`<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phoneNumberInInternationalFormat" target="_blank">Click here to open Whatsapp</a>`

In Google Chrome / **MacOs**, if I have Whatsapp Desktop installed, as soon as I click that link, I get a new tab (due to target = blank) with an Whatsapp web page containing a button 'Click here to chat', but **Whatsapp Desktop imediatelly intercepts the link and comes to the foreground and creates a new chat with that phone number**. That's the behavior I'm hoping for.

On Google Chrome **Windows**, on the other hand, Whatsapp Desktop doesn't intercept the link, so Whatsapp's web page just sits there waiting for me to click the button. The problem is that every time you click the button, you have to wait for the full Whatsapp WEB (not desktop) to load, which takes forever, specially if use this feature all the time.

I tried using `whatsapp://` syntax but it doesn't work in Windows (does nothing when clicked), and in MacOs it triggers Whatsapp Desktop but errors out unless you have that contact in your contact list already (api.whatsapp.com doesn't have this limitation).

In short: any way to make a clickable link that, on Chrome/Windows, will trigger Whatsapp Desktop instead of forcing the user to load (every time) whatsapp web?

Comment: Hello. I have same problem here, that used to run perfectly a couple months ago. Now, using windows, whatsapp:// and api.whatsapp links are asking to choose app from microsoft store, instead of opening the whatsapp desktop or the whatsapp web. Usually it would go to web or desk, deppends of what was in use, i think maybe spammers could use that, but, i not spammer, and this is a usefull feature, that we need, to make contacts easier, because customers cant have to add contacts, if they wanna just a simple and fast business contact And microsoft appstore dont have oficial apps, only fake apps .

Answer (score 4):

Building on Anand's answer, here is a reg file that adds the necessary entries.

Note: Be sure to replace YOUR_USERNAME_HERE with, um, your real Windows user-name:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp]
@="URL:whatsapp"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe\" %1"
```

Comment: This worked with closed app. Once opened doesnt work anymore. Supose it's progress

Answer (score 3):

Taking cue from Rovann Linhalis's answer, following settings worked for me in Windows 10 Pro 1809 with WhatsApp Desktop Installed

1. In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` create new key `whatsapp`
2. Then in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp` change default string value to `URL:whatsapp`
3. In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp` add new string value with value name `URL Protocol` and value data empty
4. New Key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp` with name `shell`
5. In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell` change default string value to `open`
6. New Key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell` with name `Open`
7. New Key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\Open` with name `command`
8. In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\Open\command` change default string value to
   `"C:\Users\{YOUR-PC-USERNAME}\AppData\Local\WhatsApp\WhatsApp.exe" %1`

Make sure to replace placeholder `{YOUR-PC-USERNAME}` with your username.

Example `whatsapp://send/?phone=+{countryCode}{mobileNumber}&text=HELLO%20WORLD`

Answer (score 0):

To open `whatsapp: //` in windows, just add the following registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

but I still have trouble starting a conversation after the last update.